# Numerical Accuracy: to scale or not?

Tags: numeric, floating-accuracy, numerical-methods

I am working on a n-body gravitational simulator that takes input and produces output in metric MKS units. This involves dealing with some very large numbers (like solar masses expressed in kilograms, semimajor axes of planetary orbits expressed in meters, and timescales of years expressed in seconds), which get multiplied by some very small numbers (notably, the gravitational constant, which is 6.67384e-11 in MKS units), and also the occasional very small number getting added to or subtracted from a very large number (mainly when summing up pairwise accelerations), which gets me concerned about the effects of rounding errors.

I've already taken the step of replacing all masses *m* by *Gm* (premultiplying by the gravitational constant), which significantly reduces the total number of multiplies, and makes the mass numbers much smaller, and that seems to have had a positive effect on both efficiency and accuracy, as judged by how well the simulator conserves energy.

I am wondering, however: is potentially it worth trying to do some internal re-scaling into different units to further minimize floating point errors? And if so, what kind of range (for double-precision floats) should I be trying to get my numbers centered on for maximum accuracy?

Comment: [There ought to be canonical resources about floating point topics](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info)

Comment: Well, in [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) type `double` has a maximum (decimal) exponent of roughly 300, so I would try to keep your numbers well less than 10^300 and well greater than 10^-300.

Comment: Floating point numbers are riddled with rounding problems because of their very nature. If you're expressing quantities like AU in units like metres It's likely that Floating Point representation will fall down at some point. Look for an arbitrary-precision library for your language and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if you want precise results in physical based rendering you don't want to use floats or doubles since they have **massive** rounding problems and thus introduce errors in your simulation.

If you need or want to stick with floats/double you probably should rescale around zero. The reason is that often floating point representations have a higher "density" of values around this point and tend to have fewer on the min/max sides. [Image example from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUOfP.jpg)

I would suggest that you change all values to integer based number variables. This erases rounding errors (over/underflow can still happen!) and speeds up the calculation process by an order of magnitude because normal CPUs work faster with integer operations. In case of GPU its *basically* the same but thats another story all by its own...

But before you take such an effort to further improve your accuracy i would strongly advise an arbitrary precision number library. This may come with an performance loss but should be way easier and yield better results than a rescaling of your values.

Comment: Using integers instead of double/float values may not solve the problem because integers (or long integers) have finite bits (4bytes or 8bytes etc.). Whenever you cannot use infinitely many bits (which is impossible in digital world) you face these rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the numerical mathematicians come across this problem.
At first let me remind you that you can not deal with numbers (or phsycal values) smaller than the machine epsilon for each calculation. Unfortunately the epsilon depends around which number you are analyzing. You can try eps(a) for any value of a in MATLAB, as far as I remember eps(1.0)~=2.3e-16 and eps(0)~1e-298.

That's why in numerical methods you avoid calculations using very different scaled numbers. Because one is just an ignored (smaller than its epsilon) by the other value and rounding errors are inevitable.

But what else people do? If they encounter such physical problems, before coding, mathematicians analyse the problem theoritically, they make simplifications to use similarly scaled numbers.