# How does the choice of units impact numerical precision?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, precision

I write science-related codes with Python and I was wondering how the choice of units may affect my results.

For example, if I enter a distance as 1e-9 meters or 1 nm or 10 Angstroms, I would obtain the exact same result on paper. However, I know that the representation of these quantities is different on a computer. Therefore, I would like to know how important it is to choose the relevant set of units in scientific computing to maximize numerical precision.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173149/numerical-accuracy-to-scale-or-not or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285399/is-floating-point-math-more-precise-for-values-close-to-unity

Comment: It doesn't affect it at all.  In scientific notation, whether you have 1E-9 meters or 1E0 nanometers or 10 Angstroms, you have one significant digit.  The same thing applies in floating point numbers -- the exponent is separate.  You do math on the mantissa -- the significant digits.

Answer (score 2):

*How does the choice of units impact numerical precision?*

I suggest you get as first step clarity what 'numerical precision' actually means with the side-effect of accepting the statement **It doesn't affect it at all** provided by *Tim Roberts* in the comments as short, clear and simple answer.

Usually you choose numerical precision yourself in your code by choice of the data types storing values and the way you perform calculations on these values.

The choice of units is just a choice of units and choice of data types for numerical representation of values in this units is another story.

In other words you have to know first what you actually want to do and how to achieve the results you expect.

Let's for example consider following code:

```
x     = 1.0
dx    = 0.000_000_000_000_000_1
steps = 1_000_000

for i in range(steps):
    x += dx
print(x)

x  = 1.0
x += sum([dx]*steps)
print(x)

x  = 1.0
x += dx*steps
print(x)
```

printing:

```
1.0
1.0000000001
1.0000000001
```

as evidence that the choice of the way of performing calculations is the main issue when you experience surprising results and not the *numerical precision* or choice of units as such.